# Cannot SFTP to one user, while it works with another

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, sftp, filezilla

I have a odd situation.

I am running FileZilla to access a Virtual Machine installed on my local machine using SFTP protocol.

The VM OS is RHE8.

The problem is that I have two users accounts on this VM and FileZilla can establish connection only to one of them. The same for other SFTP clients.

PuTTY runs flawlessly for both users.

I am not sure if there's anything that should be installed under the problematic user and that is installed under the "Ok" user.

SSH status is fine when I run `systemctl status sshd`.

I gave su privilege to the mentioned user and tried changing firewall settings. Everything innocuous.

FileZilla returns:

```
Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error: Could not connect to server.
```

Any hints? Thank you in advance.

Log info for the "problem" user:

```
...
2020-12-17 13:23:10 10796 1 Traçar: Sent password
2020-12-17 13:23:10 10796 1 Traçar: Access granted
2020-12-17 13:23:10 10796 1 Traçar: Opening main session channel
2020-12-17 13:23:10 10796 1 Traçar: Opened main channel
2020-12-17 13:23:10 10796 1 Traçar: Started a shell/command
2020-12-17 13:23:10 10796 1 Estado: Connected to 192.121.68.24
2020-12-17 13:23:30 10796 1 Erro: Conexão expirou após 20 segundos de inatividade
2020-12-17 13:23:30 10796 1 Traçar: CControlSocket::DoClose(2050)
2020-12-17 13:23:30 10796 1 Traçar: CControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)
2020-12-17 13:23:30 10796 1 Traçar: CSftpConnectOpData::Reset(2114) in state 3
2020-12-17 13:23:30 10796 1 Erro: Não foi possível conectar ao servidor
2020-12-17 13:23:30 10796 1 Traçar: CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(2114)
...
```

Log file to the "OK user":

```
...
2020-12-17 13:25:46 10796 1 Traçar: Sent password
2020-12-17 13:25:46 10796 1 Traçar: Access granted
2020-12-17 13:25:46 10796 1 Traçar: Opening main session channel
2020-12-17 13:25:47 10796 1 Traçar: Opened main channel
2020-12-17 13:25:47 10796 1 Traçar: Started a shell/command
2020-12-17 13:25:47 10796 1 Estado: Connected to 192.121.68.24
2020-12-17 13:25:47 10796 1 Traçar: Remote working directory is /home/ragnarok
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" account has wrongly setup profile scripts. Some of them print a message that violates SFTP protocol. There's different profile script for a terminal and non-terminal session (one that has and does not have TTY allocated). Messages can be printed only from the script used for terminal sessions. When you print a message from profile script used for non-terminal sessions, it breaks any client using a strict protocol (such as SFTP or SCP).

You will see a complete message when you log in using an SSH terminal (such as PuTTY).

Typically you will need to move the commands that print the message from `.bashrc` script to `.bash_profile`.

See also WinSCP documentation for the error message:
["Received too large (... B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 102400 B"](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet).

And a similar question about WinSCP:
[Error when use WinSCP + copy file from solaris machine to Windows machine](https://superuser.com/q/939776/213663).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a home directory set for the oracle user? I'm going to side-step the question of whether or not you should... Anyway, you can check by issuing the following command:

```
grep oracle /etc/passwd
```

Then it should appear towards the end, I think before the last colon character. If none has been set, maybe that's the issue. You'll need to setup a home directory (for which the user has permissions). To do that, issue these commands:

```
mkdir /path/to/directory
usermod -d /path/to/directory oracle
```

Let's see if that resolves your issue, but I suspect that it will...